# extjs two types of alignment in the same column

Tags: javascript, alignment, extjs4.1

I have a report and need to align the columns differently. I need to right-align the rows where you have values with numbers, and align the rows that have text to the left.

Is there any configuration / function for such a problem, or should I use CSS?

[Fiddle with the grid](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1mam)

Comment: Updated my answer, I just didn't read your ext version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do what you want on column renderer, change the align property like that and do the calcs you need:

```
renderer:function(val,cell){
        if(parseInt(val))
           cell.align='right';
        return val;
    }
```

parse int will work if your text is only made of words without any number, in your case you can check if a string have only numbers with a regex like this:

```
renderer:function(val,cell){
            if(val.match(/^[0-9]+$/))
               cell.align='right';
            else
               cell.align='left';
            return val;
        }
```

[Working fiddle here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1lvg)

Have a look to the phone column renderer.

[UPDATE]

Sorry not read your Ext version, in your case you can use my function like this:

I also updated the case with dots in the number.

```
renderer:function(val,cell){
                    if(val.match(/^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]*$/))
                       cell.style='text-align:right;';
                    else
                       cell.style='text-align:left;';
                    return val;
                }
```

[Example with your fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1mb3)